# Create an Entity Class with two foreign keys - Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

How can i create entity class for the below table which has two foreign keys of two different tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `flights_info`  (
  `airline_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `flight_infoid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `UK_mnghyk14c0ufcb2gs2k6fab40`(`flight_infoid`) ,
  INDEX `FKm5m2579nqtr1wele0bimvme8m`(`airline_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `FKlda61sltnw69kxw7b0gx6sj5s` FOREIGN KEY (`flight_infoid`) REFERENCES `flight_info` (`flight_infoid`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FKm5m2579nqtr1wele0bimvme8m` FOREIGN KEY (`airline_id`) REFERENCES `airline_info` (`airline_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class FlightsInfo  {

    @Id
    @JoinTable(name="AirlineInfo", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="airline_id"))
    private AirlineInfo airline_id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="flight_infoid")
    private FlightInfo flight_infoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your table does not have a primary key. So it's hard to point the `@Id` annotation at the right column. JPA however accepts tables without PKs as long as you have a unique column: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key

Luckily you have a unique constraint on the `flight_infoid` column, so there you should try to point your `@Id` annotation.